# Listing theorems or definitions

Tags: listings, environments, definition

I followed this [Marking the end of a definition](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/291346/marking-the-end-of-a-definition) to create an specific environment definition for my theorems.

Is there any easy way of listing all declared definitions/theorems? I want a list similar o \tableofcontent or listoffigures.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome toTeX.SE! The `thmtools` package can do this for you. Put `\usepackage{thmtools}` before `\begin{document}`, and then the command `\listoftheorems` shows them all. There are more options available, which are summarised from page 6 of the thmtoolls manual: http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/thmtools/thmtools.pdf